# Is observer pattern and React context the same?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, observable, react-context

Within the paradigm of React, what is the difference between an observer pattern and React context?

From what I understand, it looks like they're different methods to achieve the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be used for similar purposes. However, `React Context` and `Observer` are two different solutions for managing the state of a React application.

##### Observer

`Observer` is just a pattern that you can implement in our tool. It is often used in conjunction with state management library like `Redux`. It allows you to create "observable" objects, which should be automatically updated when their data changes. These components can "observe" these objects and re-render themselves when they change.

##### React Context

`React Context` is a just tool to share data between components without having to pass props down through every level of the component tree. It allows you to create a "global" state that can be accessed by any component that subscribes to it.

##### To sum up

In gerenal, while `React Context` does not use the `Observer` pattern directly, it provides a way for components to subscribe to changes in context values using the `useContext` hook. So its similar to the `Observer` pattern in that components are notified of changes automatically without having to manually subscribe and unsubscribe.